# Class 'Device' does not exist or has syntax error

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, gii

[image]
[image]

can anyone helping me?
im stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add full namesapce of `Device class`:

```
backend\models\Device
```